# ReactJS, NextJS: Trying to use checkbox to filter list of objects. Initially not toggling state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a functional component with the following states:

```js
const [events, setEvents] = useState([])
const [filteredEvents, setFilteredEvents] = useState([])
const [selectedEventIndex, setSelectedEventIndex] = useState(0)
const [ufcOnly, setUfcOnly] = useState(false)
```

I have an input checkbox.
If it's toggled to `on`, I want to filter my list.

```js
<input type="checkbox" onClick={toggleUFCOnly} onChange={e => {}} className="sr-only peer" />
```

```js
const toggleUFCOnly = () => {
    setUfcOnly(!ufcOnly)

    if (ufcOnly) {
      let filteredEvents = events.filter(event => event.organization.includes("UFC"))
      setFilteredEvents(filteredEvents)
    } else {
      setFilteredEvents(events)
    }

    setSelectedEventIndex(0)
    
  }
```

### The Issue

Checkbox is `off` initially. Tapping it to `on` does not appear to toggle `setUfcOnly`, it seems to stay false. Then another tap (to `off`) toggles `setUfcOnly`, but to `on`. Then it works "as expected" but the toggle state produces the opposite result.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Stored `ufcOnly` in a local variable and used that as the condition for my if statement

```
 let updatedUfcOnly = !ufcOnly
 setUfcOnly((prevUfcOnly) => !prevUfcOnly)
```

```
const toggleUFCOnly = () => {
    let updatedUfcOnly = !ufcOnly
    setUfcOnly((prevUfcOnly) => !prevUfcOnly)

    if (updatedUfcOnly) {
      let filteredEvents = events.filter(event => event.organization.includes("UFC"))
      setFilteredEvents(filteredEvents)
    } else {
      setFilteredEvents(events)
    }

    setSelectedEventIndex(0)
```